# jQuery - Shadowbox rebinding

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

How do I bind / initialize Shadowbox to content loaded by jQuery using AJAX?
Right now shadowbox works when I first come into the site.

However, when I swap the content with a new one loaded through AJAX, these new batch of content doesn't do the shadowbox popup, instead it just redirect to the content.

I have Shadowbox.init(shadowbox_conf); in the success but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah I just found the solution.

Shadowbox.init can't be called 2 times.

So use this instead.
Shadowbox.setup();

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

Actually, i personally had to do:

```
        Shadowbox.clearCache();
        Shadowbox.setup();
```

to get shadowbox to acknowledge the DOM change.