# Shadowbox doesn't works when it's placed inside of a jQuery ".html" function

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

Well, I'm placing a link inside of a div called "alerta" with jQuery function ".html".

Ok, then I tried to place the "rel='shadowbox'" parameter inside of my "a" tag and it doesn't works.

```
$('#alerta').html('<a href="selecao.php?id=' + 
                    avisos[i+1] + '" rel="shadowbox">' + avisos[i] + '</a>');
```

If the link is placed directly on the page, it works fine...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shadowbox initialises the elements that have a rel of shadowbox on page load. If you use jquery to add a link then the link won't have an event handler attached to it.

Try adding a class to the link, such as sbox. Then put this in your script tags instead of Shadowbox.init();

```
window.onload = function() {
   Shadowbox.setup($('.sbox'));
};

Shadowbox.init({
     skipSetup:true, // skip the automatic setup    
});

$(document).ready(function(){

       $('a.sbox').live('click',function(event){

       Shadowbox.open(this);
       //Stops loading link
       event.preventDefault();

       });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to call the

```
Shadowbox.init();
```

or somethink similar to make shadowbox aware of the newly added links.

**UPDATE**
see the answer form Lance May. Mine is obsolete.

Comment: Solve the problem. 
You have to initialize just when all the "shadowbox links" are placed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following SO post. It may help.

[jQuery - Shadowbox rebinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518745/jquery-shadowbox-rebinding)

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem. You have to initialize

```cpp
(shadowbox.ini())
```

just when all the `"shadowbox links"` are placed.

Thank you for the support.